# Beyond Bernstein functions ? Sign of the derivatives question.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

Consider functions $f(x)$ defined and real-analytic for $x>0$ , such that

for all real $x,y > 0$ and integer $n > 0$ :

$$ sign (\frac{d^n }{d^n x} f(x) ) = sign (\frac{d^n}{d^n x} f(x+y) ) $$

In other words ; the signs of the derivatives do not change over the positive reals.

Some trivial examples are $e^x$ where the signs are always positive. And $e^{-x}$ where the signs are always alternating between positive and  negative.
Bernstein functions and related things are based on this.

But what about other sign patterns ?

Such as +,+,-,++,-,+,+,-,... ?

What are typical solutions ?

Are Some Patterns forbidden ? ( not existing )

I am intrested in both periodic and nonperiodic Patterns.

I assume we can generalise Bernstein's results once we understand this.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/262444/interesting-stipulation-about-completely-monotone-functions.                                                 For instance.  Tommy1729 calls the General idea here part of " sign theory ". Not sure if it has an official name.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions

Comment: Progress has been made ... but No answers yet